# jQuery Regex Search - Store All Variable Names

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am updating my jQuery syntax highlight script for ECMAScript 5 and adding improvements for JavaScript syntax highlighting. I would like to search through my `code` `.html();` variable and store all variable names under a new variable `varNames`.

### Variable Naming Examples:

**Example 1).**

```
var a = this;
var b = that;
```

*Would add "a" and "b" to variable names list*

**Example 2).**

```
var a = this,
    b = that;
```

*Would add "a" and "b" to variable names list*

**Update: Example 3**

```
parseXSL: r => F.parseXML(r).then(F.xsl),
xsl: x => {},
xslTransform: f => {},
```

*Would add "r" "x" and "f" to the variable names list.*

> **UPDATE 2:** It appears that the above "Example 3" is a bit different whereas you could have the following:
>
> ```
> blob: r => r.blob(),
> arrayBuffer: r => r.arrayBuffer(),
> blobType: type=> r=> F.arrayBuffer(r).then(a=>new Blob([a],{type:type})),
> url: blob =>
> ```
>
> Whereas I would give 'blob' the variable highlight anywhere after
>   `url:` and not before so 'blob' would not be highlighted in
>   `r.blob(),`
>
> If this is another ballpark, please let me know and I'll remove it
>   from here, play around with any answers to see if I can get this
>   working too and if not post another question!

---

> **UPDATE 3:** It appears what I said above is consistent with all variable names! They should only be highlighted `after` they have been defined as a variable name!
>
> Any variable name and "THIS" ("example: THIS") should be wrapped in `<spanvar></spanvar>` purposely to be replaced with `<span class="var"></span>` later in my script as otherwise some bugs will occur.

### Searching For A Variable Name:

For **Example 1).**, the much easier variable name to obtain, `/(var )([a-zA-Z0-9 _]+)/` can be used, however I've not been working with regexes for long and the variable value could be anything which includes multiple commas, so I'm not sure how to find for **Example 2).**.

### Questions:

1. How can I search through my `code` variable which contains `$('pre').html();` and store all variable names?

> **UPDATE 3:** Questions
>
> 1. How do I find all desired names
>
>    - Upon finding one:
>
>      1. How do I wrap all occurrences of this word after the point of finding?

Comment: regex is not good solution for this, best way would be to split code into tokens for example `['var', 'a' ,'=' ,'this',';','\n']` this could be done using `.split` with regex and then decide if world is var

Comment: @MaciejKozieja here is my work in progress regex on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/QJgn0W/1). Am I able to use a regex, such as my work in progress, in a `.split()` function?

Comment: i also tryed to make syntax higlighter about year ago and from what i learned regex isn't good for this because its not enough aware of contex sadly :/

Comment: for me the best you can get it to asume all words folowed by = must be varibles `([a-zA-Z_]\w*)\s*=` if not using strict and skiping properties its true

Comment: @MaciejKozieja it has all been good progress so far, however with the JavaScript updates I'm doing such as this one, proving to be a bit more tricky! Am I able to use a regex, such as my work in progress, in a `.split()` function?

Comment: i sugest spliting whole data using `.split(/([-*/+\\()[\]!@#%^&`~'"<>,.?]+)/g)` then you would have [] of tokens witch you can iterate and depending on next token decide what is is `keyword` `name` `operator` `string` `number`

Comment: if you want regex maby look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/QJgn0W/8) btw i think that varible must start with `[a-zA-Z_$]`

Comment: @MaciejKozieja a friend of mine uses those variables who is an expert and says they are valid, however leaves me to try and find out answers myself which I have been trying to do for quite some time now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but I made the following assumptions according to your question:

- You are trying to find all variables in a sample text which is actually JavaScript.
- The matching needs to find variables, which are comma-separated.

If this is, what you need, here is a code snippet in JavaScript which returns a list of variables:

```js
// extract the variables
var regex = /(?:var|const|let)\s+((?:[^,=]+,)*[^,=]+?)\s*=/g;
var text = document.getElementById('main').innerHTML;

var variables = {};
var match = regex.exec(text);
while(match !== null) {
  var variableArraySplitByComma = match[1].split(',');
  for(var i=0; i<variableArraySplitByComma.length; i++) {
    variables[variableArraySplitByComma[i]] = true;
  }
  var match = regex.exec(text);
}

// values is an object to keep the values unique
var uniqueVariables = Object.keys(variables);
console.log(uniqueVariables);
```

```css
#main {
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  var test= 123;
  const hello = "this is a test.";
  let test2,variable  ={'variable':1};
  hello.html();
  test2.html();
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This seems to work however it's pulling up an error `jQuery.Deferred exception: Invalid regular expression: /e options.body` - [Example here](http://admin.bananza.org.uk/Assets/Plugins/syntax-highlight/demo.html) It also breaks my script after where I place your code.

Comment: Could you possibly made a edit/modification too so the values are stored in a variable like so; `var varNames = 'one two three'`, I feel this will aid my next step in adding another regex replace below where I have placed your code to wrap all variable names found with `<span class="var">$1</span>` as you'll see if you look at my live example.

Comment: Kindly refer to my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/421hhz6y/) too as I noticed upon texting your code does not grab all variables when not declared by `(var|const|let)`. I'm pretty new to Regexes however I'm trying to resolve to see if I can work out how to look to the end to see if there is `;` to stop and `,` to grab a new variable name.

Comment: Sorry about all these messages, I'll clear them away when I hear back from yourself, maybe it is nighttime where you are? Just want to link you to this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/421hhz6y/1/) which shows what variable names are being pulled from my example syntax highlight script input, note line 43 `const ct=r` it does not bring up `ct`, `const xsl` on line 53 and I think a few more in your `console.log`

Comment: Hi, I've updated the regular expression. It should now match much more corner cases. It still won't work for the case for(let variable of ...)` etc. because it does not have an equal sign. On matching variable names by using `;` It is very difficult to implement: just imagine a function declaration, etc.

Comment: Thank you for this however could you please check my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/421hhz6y/3/) as it seems to be catching a little more than needed at the end. I see this is particularly harder than I first imagined and I am grateful for your help! I'm going to mark this as the answer which I think you've shown more than enough help to deserve whereas any additional help is a bonus!

Comment: Yes, that is the problem I mentioned above. The regex checks for anything between `var`, `const`, `let` and an equal sign `=`. In this case, it tries to match `for (let entry of r.headers.entries()) {`, but there is no equal sign, so it goes on until it reaches one. One possibility is to check for the word `of` (drawback is, `var test, of = 123` would match too), or just skip this variable (check if there is an equal sign on the same line instead of just going on over the lines) the drawback here is that badly formatted code may have an equal sign on the same line and it skips one variable..